# Two expressions of Entropy

Tags: probability, information-theory

Given two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ taking value in ${x_1, ..., x_n}$ and ${y_1, ..., y_m}$ respectively. We define:

$p_j = P(X = x_j), 1 \leq j \leq n$

$q_k = P(Y = y_k), 1 \leq k \leq m$

$p_{jk} = P((X = x_j) \cap (Y = y_k))$

With those notations we can express the entropy of X as:
$H(X) = -\sum_{j} p_j \log(p_j)$

From the definition of the entropy we can derive two different expressions:

1.

$H(X) = -\sum_{j} \sum_{k} p_{jk} \log(p_j)$
by replacing $p_j$ by $\sum_{k} p_{jk}$

2.

$H(X) = 1 \times (-\sum_{j} p_j \log(p_j))$

$H(X) = (\sum_{k} q_{k}) (-\sum_{j} p_j \log(p_j))$

$H(X) = -\sum_{j} \sum_{k} p_j q_k \log(p_j)$

Thus, I arrive at two similar expressions of entropy for X but I guess one has to be false. Where is the error in the reasoning?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To get proper formatting for functions like $\log$, you can use `\log`. For functions that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Why does "one [have] to be false"? They are equal (as $\sum_{k}p_{jk} = \sum_k p_jp_k=p_j$)

Comment: I think one has to be false because in general $X$ and $Y$ are independent. So, $p_j p_k = p_{jk}$ is not true.

Comment: They're both correct. The individual terms are different, but the sum is the same. Whenever we're summing over all possible $y$ values, we have $\sum_yP_Y(y)P_X(x)=P_X(x)=\sum_yP_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

Comment: @Qualia As said by Karl, the terms might be different -- their sum, however, is the same. This is sometimes referred to as the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: It is clear now, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Qualia : The notation at the beginning of the question is very confusing. Are you saying that $P(X_j=x_j)=P(Y_j=x_j)$ for $j=1,...,\min(m,n)$? Even if there was a typo and you meant $P(Y_j=y_j)$  you seem to denote different probabilities by the same $p_j$. You should probably write $q_k=P(Y_k=y_k)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is

$$H(X) =-\sum_{j} \sum_{k} p_{jk} \log(p_j) =-\sum_{j} (\sum_{k} p_{jk}) \log(p_j) =-\sum_{j} p_{j} \log(p_j)  $$

The second is

$$ H(X)=  -\sum_{j} \sum_{k} p_j q_k \log(p_j) = -\sum_{j} p_j  (\sum_{k} q_k) \log(p_j) = -\sum_{j} p_{j} \log(p_j) $$

Hence, yes, both are equivalent (and correct).